# ls command - long format field separator

Tags: linux, bash, ls

Is there a way to use a different field separator for the long output of `ls`?

I have problems in parsing the output of `ls -l` because some fields, in my case the group, contain spaces.

I went through `man ls` but I didn't see any viable option for me.

Also, `IFS="AA" ls -l`, doesn't work. (I thought `ls` would work with `IFS`.)

Comment: The real answer is: Don't parse the output of `ls`. This calls for problems. What are you really trying to do? Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: That's excactly [why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Ususally you can reach you goal easily when using `stat`, `find` etc. instead.

Comment: @slhck: so far I deemed the long format of ls a source of many info in one shot. Nice reading the X-Y problem. I agree but this means questions should open and not to-the-point as the forum requires. But if users agree I'm fine with it.

Specifically for my case I excluded the group (ls -G)

Comment: It's ok to ask questions that are answerable as long as you're also fine to accept "don't do it like this" as an answer—which is the case here. The mention of the XY problem is just a hint to try and step back a little. It helps in some cases :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell `ls` to do this.

The output from `ls` is not meant to be parsed in this way.

You should use `stat` instead.  This is how you would get the group's name for `filename`:

```
stat -c %G filename
```

Comment: The presence of spaces in the group field jumbled the ls output, I was not interested in the group field (excluded via the -G option) but I thought I would solve the issue via field separators. Thanks for confirming it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -n` to get the user and group IDs as integers instead of names. If you're actually interested in those values, you'd have to convert them to names yourself after parsing.

Comment: @user2984629: The point was that numbers don't have spaces in them. But, indeed, I should have been more explicit, rather than thinking that it was obvious.